# Why is Angular 7 not rendering my bootstrap classes properly with [ngClass]

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-class

```
[ngClass]="{
                'col-12 h-100': p.length === 1,
                'col-6 h-50': (p.length >= 2 && p.length <= 4),
                'col-4 h-50': (p.length === 5 || p.length === 6),
                'col-3 h-50': (p.length === 7 || p.length === 8),
                'col-3 h-25': (p.length === 9 || p.length === 10)
              }"
```

so i have this directive on an Angular 7 div. The div also uses `*ngFor` to iterate over the `p` array. The `*ngFor` works fine and so does condition 1,2,3 & 5. for some reason it breaks on condition 4: `'col-3 h-50': (p.length === 7 || p.length === 8)`. In dev tools the bootstrap class of `h-50` is being added, bu the class of `col-3` is not. everything else works fine. anyone run into an issue like this or have any ideas?

Comment: I think it gets removed because this will be false `(p.length === 9 || p.length === 10)`, and there is also col-3 there

Comment: +1 for your input, but i think maybe you can't pass 2 classes in a string for one condition w this directive. i've removed the heights (funny enough my code does the heights automatically) and it works fine with just the `col-x`'s

Comment: @PoulKruijt you might be right, when i got it to work i eliminated redundant classes. how much u wanna bet if i flipped the order, so 9 || 10 was false, then 7 || 8 was true as the last condition, it would render right? : )

Comment: I can only assume that's why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of properties matter (apparently). The last `col-3` statement overrules the previous one. You have to split them up :)

```
[ngClass]="{
  'col-12 h-100': p.length === 1,
  'col-6': (p.length >= 2 && p.length <= 4),
  'col-4': (p.length === 5 || p.length === 6),
  'col-3 h-25': (p.length >= 7),
  'h-50': (p.length >= 2 && p.length <= 8),
}"
```